# Как добавить данные в список, из которого адаптер берет данные

Tags: java, android, retrofit

У меня 2 запроса которые отправляется с помощью retrofit.

Первый запрос отправил, получил ответ в методе onResponse
собственно response.body - это и есть этот список, но он то, в методе onResponse.

Я отправляю 2 запрос и собственно получаю ответ , тоже список response.body.

Не могу понять   Как добавить данные в список, из которого адаптер берет данные?Ну и насколько я знаю обновить их?

```
final Call<ArrayList<ProductModel>> call = (Call<ArrayList<ProductModel>>) 
service.getProducts("pagin.php","asda", 0);

call.enqueue(new Callback<ArrayList<ProductModel>>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<ArrayList<ProductModel>> call, Response<ArrayList<ProductModel>> response) {
        if (response.code() == 200) {


            for (ProductModel model : response.body()) {
                 a[0] = a[0] + model.getNameProduct();
                 Log.d("myfirst",a[0]);

                adapter = new RecyclerAdapter(response.body(), ProductsActivity.this);

                rv.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

У Адаптера есть метод `add()`, который, как ни странно, добавляет данные в адаптер. Также, начиная с определенного `API`, не помню точно с какого, у адаптера есть метод `addAll()`, который добавляет в адаптер целую коллекцию данных.
Не забудьте вызвать после добавления `notifyDataSetChanged()`

Поле:

```
private RecyclerAdapter adapter = null;
```

в `onResponse`:

```
if(adapter == null) {
    adapter = new RecyclerAdapter (...);
} else {
    adapter.addAll(response.body());
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: и где мне этот метод прописывать?
У меня адаптер создается в первом запросе в onResponse

Comment: @MartinezToni, создайте поле, в которое записывайте новый адаптер, если оно разно `null`, а если не равно - добавляйте данные в адаптер

Comment: у меня будет лист адаптеров?Что за костыль?

Comment: @MartinezToni, вы сами придумали этот костыль, ни про какой лист я не говорил.

Comment: Хорошо , скажу так, во втором запросе в методе я пишу adapter.add() - и он подчеркивает add.

Comment: т.е мой адаптер не видит данные метод и addAll в том числе

Comment: @MartinezToni, ну никто же не знает, что у вас за зверь этот `RecyclerAdapter`, от кого наследуется. В Android нет такого класса, а значит вы создали его сами

Comment: Вы правы. Значит мне в моем адаптере нужно добавить метод add(), 
что в нем написать?

Comment: @MartinezToni напишите код, который будет добавлять данные в адаптер. Какой именно код? Зависит от того, какой код в вашем классе

Answer (score 0):

1. Вам надо создать переменную типа `ArrayList<ProductModel> data = new ArrayList<>` в активити/фрагменте/синглтоне, т.е. там, где запускаете вашу задачу.
2. При создании активити/фрагмента создайте адаптер и передайте туда этот пустой список.
3. При получении данных из сети добавляйте сразу все пришедшие данные в список и уведомляйте адаптер об этом. Назначать новый адаптер множество раз не надо.

   ```
   call.enqueue(new Callback<ArrayList<ProductModel>>() {
       @Override
       public void onResponse(Call<ArrayList<ProductModel>> call, Response<ArrayList<ProductModel>> response) {
       if (response.code() == 200) {
           int prevSize = data.size();
           data.addAll(response.body());
           if(rv.getAdapter()==null){
               rv.setAdapter(new RecyclerAdapter(data, ProductsActivity.this));
           }
           rv.getAdapter().notifyItemRangeInserted(prevSize, data.size());
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: адаптер создается после первого запроса и передается список не пустой , а с данными пришедшими от сервера

Comment: @MartinezToni, ну, я изменил ответ, хлтя вам ничто не мешает изначально создать адаптер с пустым списком, а не создавать его только после прихода данных.

Comment: я не понимаю где этот список?
У меня как происходит создание адаптера.


                        for (ProductModel model : response.body()) {
                        adapter = new RecyclerAdapter(response.body(), ProductsActivity.this);
                        rv.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: @MartinezToni, я ж вам написал, что вы неправильно делаете. Ещё раз перечитайте мой ответ. Там написано, что список должен быть в активити и создавать адаптер множество раз не надоо в цикле.

Comment: а что с циклом делать тогда?

Comment: @MartinezToni, он не нужен совсем. Просто удалите его

Comment: notifyItemRangeInserted - это что такое?)

Comment: @MartinezToni, это метод, которй говорит адаптеру, что у него есть новые элементы и их нужно отрисовать